# adding notice or alert messaging not appear when using in link_to_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my `link_to_if`

```
 <%=link_to_if(post.status!='approved', "Edit", edit_post_path(post) , id: "edit_#{post.id}") %>
```

I want to add `:notice "NOT EDITABLE"` to it, but I get an error

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#index
```

my question is

How can I do it something like this, so when I click on disabled link , I can see the notice, is it possible?

```
 <%=link_to_if(post.status!='approved', "Edit", edit_post_path(post) , id: "edit_#{post.id}", notice: 'NOT EDITABLE') %>
```

**Note**: In my case, the link get disabled when is approved, but when I am clicking on it, no message shows to let the user know the is not possible to edit the post.

Comment: The syntax error is due to `notice: 'NOT EDITABLE"` which should be `notice: 'NOT EDITABLE'`

Comment: I changed now app is running but when I click on the disabled link , notice doest appear?